# How can I implement this boolean variable to this script?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this script that populates one sheet with another sheets raw data. It has specific nested IF & Do While loops, and I have one last thing I was asked to add to it.

When the user enters in the job code, I wonder if it's doable to add in an input box ONLY if `rFound.Offset(, 2).Value` = the string `Exempt`? If the value in that column says anything other than Exempt, the msg box wouldn't trigger. I know this would probably be a Boolean variable, but I can't figure out where to place it?

I want the msg box to read "Is this employee exempt, they should....."

Rest of script: (I can comment on lines if any confusion occurs)
    Sub tgr()

```
Dim rFound As Range
Dim lJobCode As String
Dim lFLSA As String
Dim lEC As String
Dim sFirst As String
Dim sResults As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Long
Dim matched As Boolean


lJobCode = Application.InputBox("Please provide a job code", "Job Code", Type:=2)
lEC = Application.InputBox("Please select EC Member", "EC Member", Type:=2)

If lJobCode = "False" Or lEC = "False" Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
rw = 8
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("A")
    Set rFound = .Find(lJobCode, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rFound.Address
        Do
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rFound.Row, 9).Value = lEC Then
                matched = True

                If rFound.Offset(, 2).Value = "Exempt" Then
                    MsgBox "Is this employee exempt, and do they work consistent hours after 8pm?"
                Else

                    sh.Cells(rw, 4) = rFound.Offset(, 0).Value
                    sh.Cells(rw, 5) = rFound.Offset(, 1).Value
                    sh.Cells(rw, 6) = rFound.Offset(, 3).Value
                    sh.Cells(rw, 7) = rFound.Offset(, 5).Value
                    sh.Cells(rw, 8) = rFound.Offset(, 6).Value
                    sh.Cells(rw, 9) = rFound.Offset(, 7).Value

                    rw = rw + 1
                End If
            End If
            Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
        Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst

        If Not matched Then MsgBox "Job Code [" & lJobCode & "] found, but not eligible for EC Member"

    Else
        MsgBox "Job Code [" & lJobCode & "] not eligible."
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: something like `if rFound.Offset(, 2).Value = "Exempt" then Userform1.Load` where your userform has an input box.

Comment: @Cyril I'm not using a userform, but I would like a simple reminder msg box to pop up. An if statement definitely works, but I can't figure out where to populate it so that it searches that column after inputting values into the `lJobCode` and `lEC` input boxes?

Comment: my suggestino would be to use a userform to collect the inputs based on "I wonder if it's doable to add in an input box ONLY if rFound.Offset(, 2).Value = the string Exempt?", though you could do the exact same thing with the input box, that it only triggers after the value is "Exempt."  you have two different input boxes popping up, whereas that can be on one userform

Comment: I don't need an input box, I just need a msg box to populate if that value exist in the row it's looping through.

Comment: `If rFound.Offset(, 2).Value = "Exempt" Then`
                        `MsgBox "Is this employee exempt, and do they work consistent hours after 8pm?"`
                   ` Else `

would this work?

Comment: ok, so that wasn't clear from the question asked.  my apologies.

Comment: @Cyril I implemented the idea in my code, should that work?

Comment: Yes, that should work, Nick, provided you want that to occur after `matched` has been declared true.

Comment: @Cyril correct, I only want the msg box to populate if that job code exists under the value selected and searched for under `lEC` variable

Comment: Golden, then you should be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting suggestion as answer so this can be marked as Answered.

```
if rFound.Offset(, 2).Value = "Exempt" then userform1.load
```

Or as a msgbox()

```
if rFound.Offset(, 2).Value = "Exempt" then msgbox("content")
```

---

**Edit1:**

If you want the data pulled when matched = true, but you then want the msgbox to pop up, try this location:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rFound.Row, 9).Value = lEC Then
    matched = True
    sh.Cells(rw, 4) = rFound.Offset(, 0).Value
    sh.Cells(rw, 5) = rFound.Offset(, 1).Value
    sh.Cells(rw, 6) = rFound.Offset(, 3).Value
    sh.Cells(rw, 7) = rFound.Offset(, 5).Value
    sh.Cells(rw, 8) = rFound.Offset(, 6).Value
    sh.Cells(rw, 9) = rFound.Offset(, 7).Value
    If rFound.Offset(, 2).Value = "Exempt" AND z = 0 Then 
        MsgBox "Is this employee exempt, and do they work consistent hours after 8pm?"
        z = 1
    End if
    rw = rw + 1
End If
```

Comment: ok so it worked, but it pops up again causing me to click OK twice, any idea why?

Comment: your code works great, but any reason why it's populating the msg box twice?

Comment: @nicklanta updated my answer with what i think you were requesting in your comments-discussion with me.  You should get a msgbox for each time rfound.offset(,2).value = "Exempt", so if it's on multiple lines then you should see it multiple times.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress it to only once?

Comment: @nicklanta added a new variable (z, please declare it as Long), which will make this happen once, as once it has been triggered, the value of z changes from 0 to 1 and the msgbox should no longer popup.

Comment: You’re the best, Thank you!!